# How do I use websockets with gjs（Gnome JavaScript）?

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I am trying to create a simple application in GJS that sends desktop notifications based on json received via WebSocket. What is the easiest way to use WebSocket in GJS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GJS you'll probably have to use libsoup for this.

The GJS documentation is at https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup30, such as the [`Soup.WebSocketConnection`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup30/soup.websocketconnection).

You'll probably also want to read the [upstream documentation](https://libsoup.org/libsoup-3.0/pt01.html) which includes some introductory material.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an example here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/examples/websocket-client.js

If you would like to use a similar API to browsers, have a look at https://github.com/sonnyp/troll